# EntityDatasource Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been looking on the web to find all the operators or syntax that you can use for the EntityDataSource control but i haven't found it on msdn could someone please provide me with the link. much appreciated. The syntax for the SELECT and WEHRE staments or operators

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: i found the link here it is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387118.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488556.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488531.aspx

Comment: Like all the syntax for the select and where statements LIKE the SQL REPLACE('', '') etc i had the page but lost it

Comment: I don't understand...you can even use Linq queries, look here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404748.aspx

just google Linq Syntax

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.aspx

UPDATE:
not actually a list but you can start from this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488529.aspx

Comment: No sorry the syntax for the SELECT and WHERE staments or operators

Comment: I found it no worries its this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387118.aspx